# How can I force install a msi file with wrong digital signature?

Tags: windows-installer

I modified a msi file, but Windows refused to install it because of the wrong signature. How can I skip the signature verification and force install it?

[image: msi installation error]

Answer (score 0):

That is the generic error message that *something* is wrong with your MSI. Most likely, your modification broke the internals of the MSI file and the Windows Installer is hinting vaguely in that direction.

Alternatively, it could be your command-line arguments are wrong.

You can try to create a log file using the `/l*v log.txt` and see if it has any detail. But if you've broken the MSI file with your modifications, the information in the log file may not be particularly helpful.